# JSON jQuery displaying parsed data problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a function

```
$.post('php/client.login.php', {username:username, password:password}, function(json){

                    var ids = json;
                    alert(json.id);

}, 'json');
```

Which returns undefined, the json data i am trying to read is this

```
[{"id":"8","client":"sam","email":"sam","username":"sam","password":"sam","case_ids":"61,63,54"}]
```

it's parsing fine but i cannot read the data, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is as posted, it should be

```
json[0].id
```

The data is wrapped in square brackets, making it an array with a single element.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
ids[0].id
```

or skip the "ids" variable and do:

```
json[0].client
```